# How can I provide an Observable in this function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

When I post a set of credentials to my api and get back data that I want to store, I get following error when the login procedure should take place.

> Error: TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was
>   expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

This is my code: I also tried instead of `res['user_id']` this version `this.user['user_id']` but then I get an error that it can't read user_id of null.

First my service which posts the credentials and takes care of the storing:

```
user = null;
  refreshToken = null;
  private authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  public authenticationState$ = this.authenticationState.asObservable();
...
checkToken() {
       this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY).then(access => {
           if (access) {
               this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(access);
               this.authenticationState.next(true);
           }
           else {
            this.storage.get(REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY).then(reaccess => {
                this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(reaccess);
                this.authenticationState.next(true);
            });
           }
       });
   }

 apilogin(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/`, { username, password })
    .pipe(
        switchMap((res: any) => {
            // run all in paralell
            return forkJoin(
                this.storage.set(TOKEN_KEY, res['access']),
                this.storage.set(USERNAME_KEY, username),
                this.storage.set(USER_ID, res['user_id']),
                this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(res['access'])
            );
          }),
    // now we know for sure storage values have been set,
    // therefore call checkToken()
        tap(() => this.checkToken()),
        catchError(e => {
            this.showAlert('Oops smth went wrong!');
            throw new Error(e);
        }));

}

apilogout() {
      this.storage.remove(USER_ID),
      this.storage.remove(REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY),
      this.storage.remove(USERNAME_KEY),
      this.storage.remove(TOKEN_KEY)
  }
```

and this is my login page.ts here I land always at error and thats where this error is logged.

```
apiSubmit() {
  console.log('Hello World');
  this.submitted = true;

  // if form is invalid => stop
  if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
  }
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.loadingEl.present();
  this.authService.apilogin(
  this.f.username,
  this.f.password)
      .pipe(tap(x => this.loadingEl.dismiss()),
      )
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log('0');
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
          console.log('1');
          this.loadingEl.dismiss();
          this.error = error;
          console.log(error);
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      );
}
```

Comment: I guess 1+ parameters of your forkJoin is a plain object

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: Are you sure that all the parameters inside `forkJoin` are observables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like all your parameters in `forkJoin` are a plain object which it will not accept and throw you that error you stated. You can just cast them into an observable super easy with rxjs and it should work fine.

```
 // import the of function
 import { of } from 'rxjs';

 // rest of your code goes here, just showing you have to import the above

 apilogin(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/`, { username, password })
    .pipe(
        switchMap((res: any) => {
            this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(res['access'])
            // run all in paralell
            return forkJoin(
                of(this.storage.set(TOKEN_KEY, res['access'])),
                of(this.storage.set(USERNAME_KEY, username)),
                of(this.storage.set(USER_ID, res['user_id'])),
                of(this.user)
            );
          }),
    // now we know for sure storage values have been set,
    // therefore call checkToken()
        tap(() => this.checkToken()),
        catchError(e => {
            this.showAlert('Oops smth went wrong!');
            throw new Error(e);
        }));

}
```